# call a method/Function after alert is shown

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is my code which opens a alert
What I want is that when i press "OK" which is on alert I can call a method/Function.

```
ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
string strScript = "<script>";
strScript += "alert('There is no Bookmarked Question Available');";
strScript += "  document.getElementById('btnReview').onclick=true";

strScript += "</script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Startup", strScript, false);
```

Comment: what is method you want call?

Comment: `alert` doesn't pass any value like `confirm`

Comment: @Murali But I have seen some websites whcih calls some function/method on pressing "OK" of this alert

Comment: @Grundy Display()  Please call it on pressing "OK" of the alert :)

Comment: @MangalPandey it's a client or server method?

Comment: forget about method...it is button click event what i want to call, Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need change your code something like this

```
ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
    string strScript = "<script>";
    strScript += "alert('There is no Bookmarked Question Available');";
    strScript += "  document.getElementById('btnReview').onclick();";

    strScript += "</script>";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Startup", strScript, false);
```

in this case after alert call onclick, for call method Display,if it a client method, something like this

```
ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
    string strScript = "<script>";
    strScript += "alert('There is no Bookmarked Question Available');";
    strScript += "  Display();";

    strScript += "</script>";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Startup", strScript, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

`alert` stops performance of your code so as soon as you will close `alert` the following method will be caused. If you need confirmation, use `confirm`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant execute when user press ok on `window.alert`

**[From Mozilla API Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert)**

> The alert dialog should be used for messages which do not require any
>   response on the part of the user, other than the acknowledgement of
>   the message.
>
> Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing
>   the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed.
>   For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a
>   dialog box (or modal window)

Also it doesnt not give any result like `window.confirm gives true/false` or any `callback method` to execute your function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a jquery/javascript function named "test"

```
function test(){
alert('There is no Bookmarked Question Available');
document.getElementById('btnReview').click();
}
```

Now just call this method from the code behind as you are doing:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Startup","test();", true);
```

That's all

Comment: One more thing this works really well if I use alert on page_Load but i want to call alert on click event and its not working there

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string strScript = "<script>";
strScript += "  if (confirm('There is no Bookmarked Question Available')) { "
strScript += "  document.getElementById('btnReview').onclick=true";
strScript += " }"
strScript += "</script>";
```